# hibernate error IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im getting this error from hibernate when trying to do a criteria search

> ERROR org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl - HHH000122:
>   IllegalArgumentException in class: packagename.domain.User, getter method of
>   property: id

For this criteria search

```
@Override
    public List<Story> findStoryByAuthor(Long userId) throws Exception {
        Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Story.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("author", userId));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        List<?> stories = criteria.list();
        return (List<Story>) stories;
    }
```

We are finding stories via the user that created it so here are the property definitions.  Trying not to clutter this so if you guys want to see more code let me know.

`Story` has a Many to One relationship with User

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
```

`Users` have no reference to story but its id property is correctly annotated

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

And lastly the database structure

Stories Table

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('stories_seq'::regclass),
  parent_id bigint,
  author_user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  title character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  dt_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  dt_last_updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now_utc(),
  thumbs_up bigint DEFAULT 0,
  thumbs_down bigint DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT pk_stories PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_stories_author_user_id_users FOREIGN KEY (author_user_id)
      REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Users Table

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_seq'::regclass),
  first_name character varying(255),
  last_name character varying(255),
  email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  user_name character varying(255),
  password character varying(255),
  phone character varying(255),
  address character varying(500),
  city character varying(255),
  state character varying(255),
  zip integer,
  preferred_language character varying(255),
  note character varying(32000),
  active boolean DEFAULT true,
  active_paid boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT users_unique_fields UNIQUE (email, user_name)
```

FYI
all basic dao functions (add, update and delete) work (full unit test coverage).  I have another criteria search, almost identical but searches on the email field and works fine.  so this error is something with the user reference

Comment: Try with `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("author.id", userId));`. if this doesnt work, maybe you have to use `alias`.

Comment: thanks that worked.  can you please make this an answer, and ill mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("author.id", userId));
```

`author` property is of class `User` so you need to reference its `id` property for the equality.